# How can I introduce navigationControllers into a tabBar setup?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar controller with two tabs and it works all fine when I want to make var1 available for both viewControllers. Now comes the question: I want to insert navigation controllers between the tab bar controller and the viewControllers: how would I change the below coding to include the navigation controllers?

```
if let barViewControllers = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers{
    let svc = barViewControllers[1] as! DaysViewController
    svc.var1 = self.var1
    let svc2 = barViewControllers[2] as! InfoViewController
    svc2.var1 = self.var1
}
```

this is what the storyboard looks like after I embedded the Navigation Controllers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just click on the first view controller in storyboard. then click editor -> embed in -> Navigation Controller

Comment: thanks for the comment. I added a picture to show the new setup after embedding. Question remains, how can I now adjust the above code to make variables available for all viewControllers.

Comment: @kangarooChris what would you want it to look like? Any specifications?

Comment: I am getting the error "Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x111389860) to '.InfoViewController'

Comment: I think you need to change the index of view controllers 
in this line let svc = barViewControllers[1] as! InfoViewController @kangarooChris

Comment: no, that did not get rid of the error. But I think that when I call for the barViewControllers instance I am now getting a list of NavigationViewControllers and  I am casting it as a ViewController by saying "as! InfoViewController"